# Setcap over SSHFS

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, sshfs, linux-capabilities

I am running a VM on my machine and have mounted a host folder inside VM using sshfs (auto-mounted via fstab).

```
abc@xyz:/home/machine/test on /home/vm/test type fuse.sshfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

That folder has an executable which I want to run inside the VM. But I also need some capabilities before running that executable. So my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Some preprocessing.
sudo setcap CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE+ep /home/vm/test/my_exec
/home/vm/test/my_exec
```

But I am getting below error :

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/home/vm/test/my_exec' (Operation not supported)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

But if I copy executable inside the VM (say in /tmp/), then it works perfectly fine. Is this a known limitation of sshfs or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) are implemented on Linux with [extended attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) (specifically the `security.capability` attribute), and not all filesystems implement extended attributes.

`sshfs` in particular does not.

Comment: So seems like this is correct, we can't use capabilities over sshfs. Even if I do setcap on host then still it wont work. So I have settled with copying executable to VM first.

Answer (score 0):

sshfs can only perform operations which the remote user is authorized to perform. You're logged into the remote host as `abc`, so you can only perform actions over sshfs which `abc` can perform -- which doesn't include `setcap`, since that operation can only be performed by root. Using `sudo` on your local machine doesn't change that.

Comment: even if they were able to log in as root on the remote machine and setcap that file there, the local machine would not know about it: there's no way to transfer file capabilities or any such extra metadata over sftp -> sshfs.

Comment: Right -- the point I'm trying to make is that using `sudo` to operate on a file on an sshfs mount will almost never have the intended effect.